# https status code 415 even content-type specified as part of Rest-request

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-mvc

My  curl request like below.

```
$ curl -ki -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8" localhost:8081/Customers-Spring-MVC-Hibernate/customer -d '{"name": "anil","age": 1,"phoneNumber": 77955,"email": "pvv.anilkumar@gmail.com","password": "Password"}'
```

where i have given the content-type:application/json but i hit 415 status code.
Here is the response i got and i could see that Content-Type:text/html is being set is it proper here..?

> Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
>   Content-Language: en
>   Content-Length: 1097
>   Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2016 05:29:27 GMT

Here is my controller definition:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addCustomer(
        @RequestBody final CustomerV1 customerDto) throws Exception
{
```

Please let me know if any workarounds..
i have tried removing and adding the charset-utf-8 but no use i still hit 415.

Adding my DTO definition if any problems here..
JSON DTO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeName("customer")
public class CustomerV1 {
    private String name;`enter code here`
    private int age;
    private long phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String password;
```

Comment: FWIW, application/json doesn't have a charset parameter, but that's probably not causing the problem here.

Comment: Its not a problem . i have tried all the possible ways .. it did not work my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding headers on your handler method as follows,

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addCustomer(
        @RequestBody final CustomerV1 customerDto) throws Exception
    {
       //your code
    }
```

From your Github link I see that you are missing following entry in your spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml file,

Also please look documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html

With this you don't need to explicitly configure JSON as your consumption.

```
<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: No use my friend.. its still the same 415.

Comment: @AnilkumarPVV I suggest to first consume service using some tool like postman and send normal http request and confirm if your spring configuration has issues or your curl. You can send curl from same tool as well.

Comment: i have tried to use DHC rest plugin for Chrome ..still i see 415 and Curl also gives me 415 .

Comment: I 'm posting my Json object too.. if any problem over there.. you can identify.

Comment: @AnilkumarPVV  provide all your configuration.

Comment: Configigurations are fine i'm able to do a get call ..but post with my Json is having a problem.. what else you need i have given my controller configuration and Json definition and curl call how i'm passing... Please let me know in specific what particular data you need i will try to publish

Comment: @AnilkumarPVV  i have updated answer. Try with consumes setting

Comment: Its done tried it before itself.. no use..my friend still hitting 415

Comment: @AnilkumarPVV now its time for github link! Create and provide

Comment: please let me know if you have any problem in accessing it.

Comment: I have tried it today ..

I have added the value attribute to the controller method and added the Json consumption to the spring mvc xml file ..

after adding i could see noclassdeffound exception being thrown and its not getting deployed..

i have removed that xml configuration and tried out with just putting the controller value addition to the function and tried to change the Method type to GET and gave a rest request it throws a 415 error .. 

anything else you suspect..?

Comment: @RequestMapping("/customer")
    public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void addCustomer(
        @RequestBody final CustomerV1 customerDto) 
 {

Comment: GET if i change and remove the @Requestbody it work fine.. i see my code getting executed.

Comment: but post is the problem .. there is something missing .. i have removed the xml config and put the value of the url and method type to POST it throws 415.

Comment: Nov 26, 2016 4:50:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet dispatcher
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException

Comment: i hit that exception when i add the Json convertion lines in the spring xml file..

Comment: Alright i'm concluding right now.. 


i have tried all the debugging and tried the steps given above in the edited section but i still hit 415. removing the @requestbody is happily executing.

Comment: @AnilkumarPVV add dependency jar also for jackson. The xml configuration will fail if the referenced jackson dependencies are not found in classpath

Comment: i have done it .. now i'm able to deploy but still been hitting with 415

Comment: @AnilkumarPVV I doubt now your json is incorrect try with {"customer" : {}}

Comment: No my Json is validate one..i have tried the one which you have given ..

still 415.

Comment: Any other trails ..?

Answer (score 0):

After the Heavy analysis and brain wreck i was able to figure out what the problem is ..

Primarily if any one is facing the same above problem like hitting 415 error...

first check on the content-types of the rest request .. it can be one of the probable root cause for the issue.. Please have a look at the below curl request for on the content-types..

curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d'{"name":"anil","age":2,"email":"anilmar.pvv","password":"anilkumar"}'http://localhost:8080/MySpringMvc/customer/add

if all the content-types are proper then lies the problem with the Jackson-jars that you have downloded..my best suggestion is to remove all the jars that you have downloaded prior you face the issue 415 and try to be constant through out the versions of the Jars.. below are the version that i have made constant and major 3 dependencies that are needed for the smooth execution please ensure that you have all the 3 jars of same version ensure that those are on the class-path..then it should work fine..below is the dependency jars that i have used and came out of the maze problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
```